# Paperclip - how to access saved file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Every one! I am using Paperclip to upload a files

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  has_many :myfiles
 end

class Myfile
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  belongs_to :model 
  has_mongoid_attached_file :file,
   :path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/:class/:id/:basename.:extension",
 end
```

My question is how to access uploaded file after it was saved? I tried:

```
    @model.myfiles.first.path
 @model.myfiles.first.url
```

it gives error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for #<Myfile:0x007fd22b336f80>
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :)

```
@model.myfiles.first.file.path
@model.myfiles.first.file.url
```

you can delegate those fields if want

```
class Myfile
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  belongs_to :model 
  has_mongoid_attached_file :file,
   :path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/:class/:id/:basename.:extension"

  delegate :url, :path, to: :file, allow_nil: true, prefix: false
 end
```

Then you can use

```
@model.myfiles.first.path
@model.myfiles.first.url
```